# Problems with code signing for ad-hoc distrubution for iPad App

Tags: ipad, itunes, entitlements

I've been trying for a weekend now to install my application via ad-hoc means for beta testing and demo purposes.  I can install from Xcode just fine, but when I try and take the app file and place it into iTunes, then try and synch, I keep getting the error "The application was not installed on the iPad because it is not signed".

I have gone through all the steps.  We went to the provisioning portal and added all the devices.  We then downloaded a distribution provisioning profile and installed that onto the development computer.  We created an Entitlements.plist file, though there was no get-task-allow attribute, so I had to add in my own.  I cleaned the targets, restarted Xcode, built the application under the ad-hoc profile with the Entitlements.plist set for the Code Signing Entitlements.

I take the app file that's generated and drag it into the Applications area of iTunes, hit synch, and I get the error.

I know I am doing something wrong, missing a step, but it must be a convoluted, obscure step that Apple doesn't have in their documentation.  So can anyone see the problem in what I'm doing?  If you could, let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  Yay.  Figured this out after some more hair-pulling.

Apparently, the build you follow is important.  I kept testing and building to the Simulator folder, and this is wrong.

To deploy to a device, you should clean all targets and then build specifically to the device.  You don't have to run it or have something plugged in, but you must build to device.  The APP that is produced is different for simulator as it is for device.

Comment: You don't need to clean all targets each time you do a device build

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "Code Signing Entitlements" build setting in your target to "Entitlements.plist"?

Comment: I did.  I think it was a problem with what I was deploying to.  I kep trying to use the simulator's app file.